# Navigation method/s in criteria fetch joins in JPA 2.1

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

While using fetch joins in JPA criteria, there is no navigation method can be seen. Given below an example.

```
Root<UserTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(UserTable.class));
Fetch<UserTable, StateTable> fetch = root.fetch(UserTable_.stateTable, JoinType.INNER);
```

To navigate through the entity in question, this `Fetch` type is required to be cast to a join like as follows.

```
Join<UserTable, StateTable> join = (Join<UserTable, StateTable>) root.fetch(UserTable_.stateTable, JoinType.INNER);
```

The navigation method `get()` is available after this cast just like,

```
join.get(UserTable_.firstName);
```

Is this type cast portable (while it works on EclipseLink (2.5.1) and Hibernate (4.3.5))? Is there any other ways to do the same? Is there any specific reason as to why criteria fetch joins do not support a navigation method?

---

**UPDATE :** <sub>(I would still consider this to be just a partial answer. Hence, not written in the answer section)</sub>

This is very well spotted on [here](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.in/2012/04/objects-vs-data-and-filtering-join.html#Filtering) by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416206/james) as to why a navigation method in `FETCH JOIN` (including aliasing in JPQL) is highly discouraged and not recommended especially in `OneToMany` relationships (and consequently not directly provided/supported in `FETCH JOIN`s):

> EclipseLink allows you to use an alias on a `JOIN FETCH`. This support
>   was intended for `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` relationships, to avoid having
>   to join it twice just to get an alias, as well as to allow using it in
>   an `ORDER BY` or in other ways **that would not filter the results and
>   alter how the objects are built**. But, there is nothing stopping you
>   from using it with a `OneToMany` to filter the contents of the fetched
>   `OneToMany` results.

You may want to read up the entire blog with the given examples instead. To my experience, Hibernate (at latest versions) also allows us to do this.

In general, I personally do not use aliasing in `OneToMany` relationships to navigate through the target entity (the one which has the foreign key) that indeed should not be needed in real projects at best but it is required in `OneToOne` and/or `ManyToOne`.

Comment: anything that is outside the spec is clearly not portable, by definition.

Comment: The JPA `CriteriaBuilder` API itself is from hell :)

Answer (score -1):

You may call

```
Join<UserTable, StateTable> join = root.join("prop", JoinType.INNER);
```

See here: 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join(java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join%28java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType%29)

Comment: that does a join. It doesn't do a fetch.

Comment: `root.join("prop", JoinType.INNER);` does not result in a fetch join as the previous comment indicates.