# JPA - Why cast Fetch to Join

Tags: jpa, jpa-criteria

Why is it necessary sometimes to cast?

```
Join<X, Y> a = (Join) Fetch<X, Y> ...
```

For Example:

```
Root<Person> personRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Join<Person, Loan> loanJoin = (Join) personRoot.fetch("loan", JoinType.INNER);
loanJoin.fetch("borrower", JoinType.LEFT);
```

What is the reason for not doing:

```
Fetch<Person, Loan> fetchJoin = personRoot.fetch("loan", JoinType.INNER);
fetchJoin.fetch("borrower", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: Since a `javax.persistence.criteria.Fetch` isn't necessarily a `javax.persistence.criteria.Join`, then it makes no sense (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to cast `Fetch` to `Join` when I wanted to get benefits of both.

- `Fetch` allows eager loading when annotations are not working see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25631785/2202712
- `Join` allows adding restriction/order on an attribute from joined relation

e.g., Say you want to get all `Employee` together with info about their departments and home countries as a single select query with two inner joins. This is possible by adding a `root.fetch(...)` each for `department` and `homeCountry`. If you also wish to order employees based on the population of their respective home countries (please assume you wish to), you will need a `Join`

```
Root<Employee> root = query.from(Employee.class);
root.fetch("department");  // <- for an eager join
Join<Employee,Country> joinCountry = (Join) root.fetch("homeCountry");  // <- for an eager join & orderBy
query.select(root).orderBy(builder.asc(joinCountry.get("population")));
Query<Employee> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
List<Employee> employees = q.getResultList();
```

Above code fires a single `select *` to the db

```
select
    employee0_.emp_id as emp_id1_0_0_,
    department1_.department_id as depart1_2_1_,
    country2_.country_id as countr1_3_2_,
    employee0_.salary as salary2_0_0_,
    department1_.name as name3_0_0,
    country2_.continent as continent4_0_0
from
    employee employee0_
inner join
    department department1_
        on employee0_.department_id=department1_.department_id 
inner join
    country country2_
        on employee0_.country_id=country2_.country_id 
order by
    country2_.population asc
```

Comment: I think that it doesn't work anymore. I had many troubles with casting Fetch to Join. Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The definite answer is here: [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq)

Basically JPA provides `@OneToMany` that requires fetching of **all related entities** to `Collection`. If you allow aliasing to `Fetch` (as `javax.persistence.criteria.Path.get(String)`) it is possible to add `where` or `on` expression that limits `Collection` breaking JPA Java model assumptions.

There are no problem with `@*ToOne` joins and so some JPA implementations allow casting of `Fetch` to `Join` assuming you understand what are you doing ))

Other reading:

- [How to perform a join fetch in JPA Criteria without unchecked casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450323/how-to-perform-a-join-fetch-in-jpa-criteria-without-unchecked-casting)
- [how to do a JOIN FETCH in jpa criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553489/how-to-do-a-join-fetch-in-jpa-criteria)
- [Using the JPA Criteria API, can you do a fetch join that results in only one join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306655/using-the-jpa-criteria-api-can-you-do-a-fetch-join-that-results-in-only-one-joi)
- [Navigation method/s in criteria fetch joins in JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104531/navigation-method-s-in-criteria-fetch-joins-in-jpa-2-1)