# How to perform a join fetch in JPA Criteria without unchecked casting?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I need to do a JOIN FETCH in JPA Criteria using a static metamodel, however I'm at a loss on how to do it without getting an unchecked exception warning.

Suppose we have a Thing entity with a lazily-initialized Other entity inside it. I want to retrieve Things with fetched Others, where other.someField="someValue". This is roughly how I would do it:

```java
public List<Thing> getThings() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Thing> cq = cb.createQuery(Thing.class);
    Root root = cq.from(Thing.class);

    // This gives an unchecked cast warning:
    Join<Thing, Other> other = (Join<Thing, Other>) root.fetch(Thing_.other);

    cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(other.get(Other_.someField), "someValue"));

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

However, since the Join and Fetch interfaces have nothing in common, I get an "unchecked cast" warning. I would like to get rid of that warning (without using @SuppressWarnings).

I suppose I could do it this way:

```java
cb.equal(root.get(This_.THING).get(Other_.SOMEFIELD), "someValue"))
```

But I'm doubtful whether it's better, seeing as I'm operating on Strings here (so no type safety).

What is a cleaner way of achieving the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch method is not supposed for creating JPA joins. In JPA join is used to create where conditions, not for loading data. This is different from native SQL. For JOIN use:

```
Join<Thing, Other> other = root.join(Thing_.other);
```

Independently collection can be loaded with or without calling join():

```
root.fetch(Thing_.other);
```

Comment: The problem is using this method, the resulting query will produce two joins :

`Root<Thing> root = query.from(Thing.class); SetJoin<Thing, Other> othersJoin = root.join(Thing_.others); root.fetch(Thing_.others);`
will produce:
`SELECT foo_0.id, bar_1.id, bar_1.foo_id FROM foo AS foo_0 INNER JOIN bar AS bar_0 ON foo_0.id = bar_0.foo_id INNER JOIN bar AS bar_1 ON foo_0.id = bar_1.foo_id`
Depending on the number of records, the query can increase drastically. In my case it was 10 times longer.

Comment: I found a bigger issue: I have an Order By clause with distinct, and it requires the field to be part of the selection. Because I have two joins, one for fetching and another for conditions, even though I am fetching the entity whose attribute is in my Order By condition, the Order By references the Join alias, not the fetch alias, causing an error on the database level.
So it seems that in practice this separation does not work.